# scipy fsolve() method throws different first value when the second value changes

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, fsolve

I am trying to get the roots of `f(x) = x**3-100*x**2-x+100`

I know two of the roots are `1`, `100`. So set guesses close to this should work.

This is the code (with two different guesses):

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def f(x): return x**3-100*x**2-x+100
s0 = fsolve(f, [2,80])
s1 = fsolve(f, [2,75])  # <-- changed from 80 to 75

print(s0)
print(s1)
```

result:

```
[  1. 100.]
[ -1. 100.]   # <-- first argument is -1
```

I was expecting to get the same result twice.

So my question is why when I changed the **second input parameter** in the list, did the **first value in the result** change from `+1` to `-1` ?

additional notes (based on the comments: I run this extra piece of code to see what is returned.

```py
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def f(x): return x**3-100*x**2-x+100

for i in range(65, 85):
    x = fsolve(f, [2,i])
    print(i, x)
```

and get this back:

```
65 [-1.  1.]
66 [ 1.94287787 65.87673804]
67 [ 2. 67.]
68 [  1. 100.]
69 [  1. 100.]
70 [  1. 100.]
71 [  1. 100.]
72 [ -1.00000028 100.        ]
73 [  1. 100.]
74 [  1.00000006 100.        ]
75 [ -1. 100.]
76 [  1. 100.]
77 [  1. 100.]
78 [  1. 100.]
79 [  1. 100.]
80 [  1. 100.]
81 [  1. 100.]
82 [  1. 100.]
83 [  1. 100.]
84 [  1. 100.]
```

I appreciate that `-1` is the third root, but it was never the closest root given the first element of the guess is always `2`.

And also, we see that `fsolve(f, 2)` in isolation returns `array([1.])`...

Comment: ‐1 is also a root.

Comment: `fsolve` doesn't know that you are trying to find two separate roots of a scalar equation.  You passed in an initial guess that has length 2, so `fsolve` is solving a single problem that has two variables.  There are nine possible solutions, and in general, `fsolve` can not guarantee that it will return the solution closest to the given initial guess.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser,  this is correct, but it was never a closest root, so expect to find `-1` when the initial guess is, say `-5`, like this `fsolve(f, -5)` - > `array([-1.])`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser,  i appreciate the non-guarantee for closest root, but the question is why does it flip when the first guess is continuously `2`. It appears as though the second guess has affected the first guess ?   is this the case ?  ...i thought that the guesses were independent of each other...  was my understanding therefore incorrect ?

Comment: As @Askold Ilvento notes in an answer, `fsolve` does not accepts "guesses"; it accepts a single point.  When you pass in [2, 80], you are telling `fsolve` that you as solving a single system of two equations.  The iterative algorithm will be applied once, with iterates being arrays of length 2.  So yes, the "second guess" will affect the "first guess", because you have actually selected a different point in the 2-d plane at which to start the iterative algorithm.  The two components do not evolve independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fsolve` solves does not accept *guesses*. It takes only **one** guess for a multidimensional system

```
f1(x1, x2, x3...) = 0
f2(x1, x2, x3...) = 0
f3(x1, x2, x3...) = 0
…
```

When you run `fsolve(f, [2,80])`, you attempt to solve a 2D system.
When you run `fsolve(f, [2])`, you attempt to solve a 1D system.
You may try to solve a 3D system with `fsolve(f, [2,80, 12])` :)

`fsolve` passes `numpy.ndarray` to your callback `f` and it’s because NumPy magic `f(x)` returns multidimensional output in your case.
Most people have to write different codes for each function in the system to get multidimensional output from a callback they pass to `fsolve`. And in general, such functions are supposed to be different. `fsolve` does not assume that they can be the same, but it seems `fsolve` can handle the case with the same functions quite efficiently.

The Powell method (or its MINPACK modifications used in scipy.fsolve) changes elements of multidimensional vector `x = (x1, x2, x3, ...)` simultaneously. I should admit that I cannot understand MINPACK’s Fotran code. But it should be some kind of linesearch. And when you change the 2D initial point you change the starting point for the first line in 2D space that is constructed inside the root-searching procedure. That's why changing "the second guess" influences on "the first result".

If you do not want such dependence run `fsolve` independently for each guess.

Comment: thank you for clarifying, this makes good sense in the context of the question.